# Using forecast errors to cross-sectionally compare quality of two different data sources (using sLDA)

Tags: forecasting, panel-data, model-comparison

At a high level conceptually, I have two different data sources for panel data and I am trying to compare the quality of each data source by comparing forecast errors from models predicting an outcome Y using the two different data sources. I'm particularly interested in studying cross-sectional variation in forecast quality--i.e., is one data source particularly good/bad at predicting the outcome variable for a particular subset of the observations? Basically, I want to know which data source is better under different sets of circumstances.

I've tried looking into the literature on forecasting, but have failed to find clear guidance on my problem (perhaps I'm just not looking the right way). Boiled down, my situation has the following characteristics:

- I want to compare 2 models across the same population
- I'm comparing non-nested models
- I have panel data and the models are multivariate
- I'm interested in the *cross-sectional* variation in forecast accuracy. That is, I want to know *when* a particular model works better (i.e., for which cross-sectional slices of the population). I think this last part of my problem is the part that is trickiest to deal with.

In terms of my actual implementation, I'm actually trying to compare the predictive ability of sLDA topics created from running a topic model on the same document written in two different languages (essentially two different "databases" of differing noisiness), but I think my conceptual issue trying to understand comparing forecast errors is sort of two steps before thinking about how the specific mechanics of sLDA fit in.

Comment: subspace linear discriminant analysis?

Comment: supervised latent Dirichlet allocation